# Change a css property of a logo when toggle is clicked

Tags: javascript, css, toggle

I want to change a css property (z-index) to a logo in the navigation bar when i click on toggle.
Than I need to change that property back when that toggle is closed. Is this possible?

My toggle has a class "ubermenu-responsive-toggle-main"
My logo has a class "header-logo"
Open toggle has a class "ubermenu-responsive-toggle-open"

Comment: provide some code please

Comment: Please provide an example code so we can analyse your issue

Comment: post your code so that someone can help

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your `z-index` in a class in your `css` file -

**CSS**

```
.z-index-high {
    z-index: 999;
}
```

**JS**

```
toggleBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    toggleBtn.classlist.toggle("ubermenu-responsive-toggle-open");
    if(toggleBtn.classlist.contains("ubermenu-responsive-toggle-open") {
        logo.classlist.add("z-index-high");
     } else logo.classlist.remove("z-index-high");
});
```

Its not mandatory to put the `z-index` property in a css class. Its just easier to deal with 
 because of `classlist` propoerty present in DOM nodes.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>

<div id="demo" customAttribute="value1">this text toogles</div> 
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
   elm=document.getElementById("demo");
  elm.setAttribute("customAttribute",elm.getAttribute("customAttribute")=="value1"?"value2":"value1");
}
</script>

<style>
[customAttribute=value2]{
visibility: visible; 
}

[customAttribute=value1]{
visibility: hidden;
}
</style>

</body>
</html>
```

This code is a simple toggle that will hide then show a text when you click a button.
The key is the line
    elm.setAttribute("customAttribute",elm.getAttribute("customAttribute")=="value1"?"value2":"value1");